# Do ELF object files store file system paths for dependent libraries?

Tags: ld, elf, static-linking, abi, object-files

When we link executables with `ld`, we give a list of libraries that the executable depends upon. Is this the only source of the location information for these libraries, or is some information about the preferred version of dependent libraries stored as metadata in the object files?

The specific issue is this: If I link two dependent libraries `lA` and `lB`, which both depend upon a third library `lC`, and I place references to these libraries on the link line. It appears that C++ class methods in `lA` are calling into a different version of `lC` than class methods in `lB`. How is this possible? I know this from looking at a backtrace in `gdb`.

Comment: With static libraries, what you've described *can not* possibly happen. Therefore, either your description is wrong, or your interpretation of observed results is wrong. Unfortunately, you didn't describe either in sufficient detail to replicate your experiment, and thus no further help can be provided. Edit your question, show a minimal example, and all will be revealed.

Answer (score 1):

They might. `DT_RPATH` is used for symbol resolution. They also include the full object name, that *might* include a version number, and if the library uses versioning correctly, then the symbols don't actually collide with each other.

I can send you to my blog for a couple of insight into `DT_RPATH` and `DT_SONAME`:

- https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/06/the-why-and-how-of-rpath/
- https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/10/a-shared-library-by-any-other-name/
- https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/10/linkers-and-names/

Comment: I should have made clearer that I'm asking about static linking.

Comment: You mean linking of static libraries? Then it sounds a bit more interesting and might be a bit of a different problem. If those class methods are inline, the compiler may have emitted different copies of the symbols in each of `libA` and `libB` objects, thus changing addresses. Otherwise it maybe visibility rules issues.